# Pattern match on inner trait cannot be checked at run time?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I tried pattern matching on an inner trait but it looks like this cannot be done. It also matches inner trait instances from other objects. It matches only inner (abstract) classes.

I cannot find why an inner trait cannot be checked at run time. Any suggestions?
With the code below I get this warning for 'def patternMatchA1': 'The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time.'

```
trait A0
case class X() {
  trait A1 extends A0
  case class A() extends A1

  def patternMatchA1(a: A0) = a match {
    case a: A1 => true //The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time.
    case _ => false
  }

  def patternMatchA(a: A0) = a match {
    case a: A => true
    case _ => false
  }
}

val Xa = X()
val Xb = X()
Xa.patternMatchA1(Xa.A()) //true
Xa.patternMatchA1(Xb.A()) //true -> I expected this to be false

Xa.patternMatchA(Xa.A()) //true
Xa.patternMatchA(Xb.A()) //false
```

scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gj2Tb6QaShiNNeRMMliwsQ

Comment: why it should be false? it is only false if `a` it's not an `A1` which clearly is

Comment: It should be false, just like the second case. This code is supposed to test path dependent types. But there is some limitation in the compiler.

Comment: Maybe related to https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4440 ?